# Is there a way to select a folder using browse and send absolute path of it to the server?

Tags: html

I noticed that with html5 an entire folder can be uploaded like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file_input[]" id="file_input" multiple="" webkitdirectory="">
```

this will send back to the server all files found in the folder.

However, is there a way to get an absolute path to the folder as a string and pass that to the server?

For example: If the path is `C:\documents\my_folder` then I would like to send that to the server as a string rather than sending all files inside `my_folder`

Comment: I guess I remember the browser does not have access to that path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav