# How would I find a html files parent directory name?

Tags: javascript, html, parent

I need to know a html files parent directory so I can access a file in it named the same as the directory. I just need the directory name as a string.

Comment: Show us your best attempt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714462/is-there-a-way-to-select-a-folder-using-browse-and-send-absolute-path-of-it-to-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
window.location.pathname
```

But again depends on what you are trying to achieve, show some code.

Comment: `window.location.pathname` is a URI, it doesn't necessarily include any file name. e.g. for this page it's `/questions/25717173/how-would-i-find-a-html-files-parent-directory-name`.

Answer (score 0):

## Background

As @NewUser says, use `window.location.pathname` if you want only the path. Example: on this page, that gives:

```
/questions/25717173/how-would-i-find-a-html-files-parent-directory-name
```

You indicated that you are dealing with an HTML file, though, which implies a file name and file ending (`.htm`, `.html`, etc.). So, to get the full URL, minus the file name, you can try using `.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '')`, like this:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz.htm';
alert(url.replace(/[^\/]+$/, ''));
// gives http://www.example.com/foo/bar/
```

## Putting It All Together

To do it without hard-coding the URL:

```
var path = window.location.toString().replace(/[^\/]+$/, '');
alert(path);
```